# After hover, text seems always showing

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, css-selectors

I have two `div` and one is on top of the other. Both `div` has a `span` with texts are ellipsis , and what I want to do is when hover onto `span`, showing the text. But right now, after first hover, the next time when you hover onto top `span`, the text of second `span` is still there, kinda like `transparent`.

Edit: I was using css before instead of Jquery, but after recent Chrome updates, my hover does not work, so I have to use Jquery instead.

Old CSS:

```
.hover:hover {
overflow: visible;
white-space: normal;
min-width: 200px;
background-color: #E5E5E5;
z-index: 1000;
position: relative;
font-family: Verdana;
```

}

Here is the [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jjn522xz/)

```js
$('.hover').on('mouseover', function() {
  $(this).css({
    'overflow': 'visible',
    'white-space': 'normal',
    'min-width': '200px',
    'background-color': 'rgba(229,229,229,1)',
    'z-index': '100',
    'position': 'relative',
    'font-family': 'Verdana'
  })
})

$('.hover').on('mouseleave', function() {
  $(this).css({
    'font-size': '15px',
    'color': '#15428B',
    'background-color': 'rgba(255,255,255,0)',
    'width': '200px',
    'text-overflow': 'ellipsis',
    'white-space': 'nowrap',
    'overflow': 'hidden'
  })
})
```

```css
.box {
  height: 20px;
  float: left;
  clear: left;
  border: 1px solid black;
  width: 200px;
}

.hover {
  font-size: 15px;
  color: #15428B;
  width: 200px;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='box'><span class='hover'>Hello World!Hello World!Hello World!Hello World!Hello World!Hello World
</span></div>
<br>
<div class='box'><span class='hover'>Hello World!Hello World!Hello World!Hello World!Hello World!Hello World
</span></div>
```

So, as I mentioned it may be a chrome issue. I uninstalled my chrome and am using Chrome Canary, it is working, both with the old CSS method and @Toastrackenigma's method

Answer (score 1):

As OP says in the comments of this answer (but not in his question), plain CSS is not an option for him. Although I am still not 100% convinced about this requirement, here is a pure jQuery solution:

```js
 $('.hover').on('mouseover', function(){
  $(this).css({
    'overflow': 'visible',
    'white-space': 'normal',
    'min-width': '200px',
    'background-color': 'rgba(229,229,229,1)',
    'z-index': '100',
    'position': 'relative',
    'font-family': 'Verdana'
  })
 })

 $('.hover').on('mouseleave', function(){
  $(this).removeAttr("style")
 })
```

```css
.box {
  height: 20px;
  float:left;
  clear: left;
 border:1px solid black;
  width: 200px;
}

.hover {
  font-size: 15px;
 color: #15428B;
 width: 200px;
 text-overflow: ellipsis;
 white-space:nowrap;
 overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class='box'>
   <span class='hover'>Hello World!Hello World!Hello World!Hello World!Hello World!Hello World
  </span>
</div>
<br>
<div class='box'>
  <span class='hover'>Hello World!Hello World!Hello World!Hello World!Hello World!Hello World
  </span>
</div>
```

Comment: The reason why I am using jquery is because after recent chrome update, every time after my hover, the text disappears and in development tool, text is not hidden. So I switched to jquery.

Comment: @lilixiaocc So, you can't use plain CSS to do this? That should have been stated in your question, as this is the obvious solution to your problem. You should probably go back and edit it in.

Comment: @lilixiaocc your comment makes no sense - starting from *recent chrome update* and the reason you're using jQuery for something so banal.

Comment: Sorry, it may sound weird, but after applying your changes, the text starts to disappear after hovering, just like the CSS method. I do not know if it is because of my computer or what, chrome version is 60.0.3112.90.
I wish I could post a gif somewhere

Comment: @lilixiaocc This is how it looks on my machine: http://imgur.com/a/7wjXf

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this:

```
.box:first-child:hover ~ .box > span {
    display: none;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/jjn522xz/1/

Comment: As OP says in the comments of my answer, he cannot use CSS to do this.

Comment: @Toastrackenigma, thanks for letting me know. I hadn't seen that comment. I leave my answer in place for now as general information.

Comment: Yeah, it's actually a really good solution to the problem - I got caught out doing a CSS answer too. Seems like a bit of a weird requirement TBH.

Answer (score 0):

First, using `text-overflow: ellipsis` with fixed `width`, `white-space: nowrap;` and `overflow:hidden` won't work unless you define your `span` tag as `display: inline-block` or `display: block`.

Secondly, that overlapping occurs due to not using `z-index` and `position: relative`.

I have made some changes in your [**JSFiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/vivekkupadhyay/jjn522xz/3) accordingly, please check.

*PS: Its nothing to do with the latest Chrome Updates.*